# Shouldn't there be a determinism behind all random processes, so even the ones seen in quantum mechanics?

Tags: probability, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

Behind all random processes lay deterministic principles. Behind the throwing of a dice there are deterministic processes at work that fix the outcome. Our lack of knowledge is due to the chances in predicting the òutcome. The interaction of the dice with its surroundings is just too complicated to know exactly.

Quantum mechanics changes the situation. Even for the simplest system, perfectly comoutable in classical mechanics, a chance on certain uotcomes is present. Even if we know everything about the system there will be an inherent chance in the process which can't be eliminated by knowing more.

But how can chance be inherent to Nature? How can it be that nothing determines the next step in a process? The chance distribution (the wave function) behaves deterministic but the outcomes of a measurment don't. It is a pure chance which side a quantum mechanical dice will show when thrown.

But how can this be? I know we are used to classical deterministic processes. We can't imagine it to be different. Bur I can't imagine processes to be purely chance governed either. There is determinism in the changing chance distributions but this doesn't give me solace or ease. Now I'm not looking for the easy way but some solace is welcome.

Comment: You mean behind all *classical* random processes lay deterministic principles. Even that is not quite true, see [Norton's dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome). And we can surely *imagine* pure chance with undetermined outcomes even without quantum mechanics, (classical) probability theory even makes it mathematically precise. We may not *like* the arbitrariness of it, but not from lack of imagining, it is just a coping bias that demands hidden causes to reduce the stress from lack of control. Solace and ease come with the habit of overriding it.

Comment: @Conifold I like the idea of pure chanca very much.  But I cannot imagine it to exist. How it comes about. Somehow it presupposes determinism. What determines an outcome? Things we dont kbow. But I imagine you can logically suppose the existence of pure chance. Nothing cuses in this case. Except for the chance, that is.

Comment: You already imagined it, or you wouldn't be able to like or dislike it. How something may come about is not needed for imagining it, and in this case the task is nonsensical. *It* (pure chance) does not presuppose determinism, *you* do when asking about a cause of something causeless. It is like asking what is the color of something meant to be colorless, like electron. Breaking a thought habit is hard, but something appearing where nothing was before, without anything precipitating it, is perfectly imaginable, not just logically supposable.

Comment: @Conifold Indeed. Something can appear out if the blue. But the appearing presupposes time. Somethinb is not there and then it is. Withiut a cause. Like an electron. But how does the electron know when to appear? And that is has to do together with its antiparticle? Its easy enough to imagine it coming out of the blue and just stating there is no cause but then you are implicitly implying there is nothing that determines their appearance (apart from chance).  What justifies this assumption? The very fact that they appear out of the blue?

Comment: "*The only reason for time is so that everything doesn't happen at once*". But it could. And pre-determining presupposes time just as well. With chance you are *explicitly* positing that nothing determines the appearance. And why not? Electron needs to "know" no more than it needs to be colored. What justifies the opposite assumption of determinism? That it is more familiar and comforting? Why assume either? Some things can be determined and others just not. No need to reduce everything to one or the other exclusively, especially by making up hidden causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deterministic theories have not been ruled out. And there are no experiments which can rule out deterministic theories completely.

But there are many philosophers of physics open the possibility of fundamental randomness. Robert Nozick says the original Principle of Sufficient Reason is contradicted by quantum indeterminacy. Where there are no causes (e.g. no answer to why this atom decayed right now), there are still reasons for there being no cause according to Nozick's weaker PSR.

Another philosopher Hans Reichenbach is at least partially open to "causal anomalies":

"We see now how the thesis concerning indistinguishable particles is to be qualified. In precise language we cannot simply say: the particles are indistinguishable. We must say: either the particles are indistinguishable, or their behavior displays causal anomalies. We are left the choice of selecting one or the other interpretation. Neither is "more true than the other"; two are equivalent descriptions. However, only one of the two descriptions supplies a normal system, that is, a system free from causal anomalies; this is the description according to which the particles are indistinguishable."

"Now we saw that for materially genidentical particles Bose statistics leads to causal anomalies. We thus arrive once more at a situation in which a causal anomaly has become a property of observables. This conclusion supplies inductive evidence against the hypothesis of determinism and for the synoptic principle (i.e. can't measure certain properties like position and momentum at same time (I think))."

"Conversely, if we accept the synoptic principle, its combination with Bose statistics leads to the result that there is no material genidentity...It follows that...there is no material genidentity in the physical world." from Interpreting Bodies by Castellani, Elena.

So we must give up material genidentity (that anything of substance be it particles, atoms, billiard balls, humans, etc has continuity through time) if we want to save determinism. As I understand it, giving up material genidentity still isn't sufficient for determinism; we must still search further for deterministic underpinnings to observed indeterminancy, but we do have to give up on material continuity.

The answer to your question "must there be determinism" is no, shown by the fact that professional philosophers are open to fundamental randomness.

Comment: The moment I doubted genidentity I read you doubting it too too. At least finding something that gives rise to jumpy behavior.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Quantum measurements and entanglement show jumpy behavior. The question is why and how this jumpiness is observed. Some philosophers are okay with saying random really is random.

Comment: I dont have a problem with that either. I cant imagine though how it comes to be.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder "I cant imagine though how it comes to be". You're not alone. In fact *understanding randomness* is almost paradoxical. There is no explanation; random is random. Like magic, an answer/outcome/measurement "just appears". We can say no further.

Comment: I think I go along with that. It is even comforting as I see it now. No more uneasiness or no solace...:)

Answer (score 0):

The first line of this question imports an assumptive believe as though it were an objective fact. What is the basis for the claim that there are deterministic principles behind every random process?

Randomness is a model: a way of organizing that-which-we-do-not-know. When we say an event is 'random', what we mean is that the event is influenced by forces that we have not (yet) analyzed and do not (yet) understand. Sometimes we can make effective claims about the distribution of such events, which is useful. But event-distributions are correlations, not causal theories. They tell us next to nothing about the forces underlying random events.

This is the hardest part of science: recognizing that we do not know something, and consciously avoiding the imposition of self-soothing assumptive bias. Science (like philosophy) is uncaring when it comes to our comfort zones.

Comment: This answer repeats what I have summarized in the question. In the case of quantum mechanics it is said that there is nothing more to knowtvhan the pure chances. Randomness in the (classical) world appears as a measure of our ignorance. I we knew all then in principle we could know everything. In qm we cannot know everything in principle. There is nothing to know. Unlesscyiu incorporate hidden variables or something like that. The strange thing about qm is that the chances are inherent to Nature.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: No, that's not quite what I said.  The claim that there are deterministic processes at work behind random events is an unvalidated assumption. The QM claim that there is *nothing* behind random events is also an unvalidated assumption. In both cases, we don't know what's happening (period, full stop); we just know that a statistical model works. Any assumptions we make might be convenient, useful, and/or comforting, but that's all they are.

Comment: But there *are* deterministic processes behind the throwing of a dice.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder: Pe *presume* there are deterministic forces behind the throw of dice. But we can't specify precisely what those are, so we don't *know* that for a fact. I mean, what if I suggested that the outcome of a toss of dice was in fact dependent on quantum events: e.g., that the trajectory of thrown dice is a chaotic (non-linear) function so sensitive to initial conditions that the actual outcome is determined by the quantum state of various particles in their makeup or surroundings? How could we prove that wrong?